# action parameters routing not working in Zend framework routes.ini

Tags: zend-framework, routes, zend-route, custom-routes

I'm trying to set up a route in Zend Framework (version 1.11.11) in a routes.ini file, which would allow be to match the following url:

```
my.domain.com/shop/add/123
```

to the `ShopController` and `addAction`. However, for some reason the parameter (the number at the end) is not being recognized by my action. The PHP error I'm getting is

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for ShopController::addAction(), called in...
```

I know I could set this up using PHP code in the bootstrap, but I want to understand how to do this type of setup in a .ini file and I'm having a hard time finding any resources that explain this. I should also point out that I'm using modules in my project. What I've come up with using various snippets found here and there online is the following:

application/config/routes.ini:

```
[routes]
routes.shop.route = "shop/add/:productid/*"
routes.shop.defaults.controller = shop
routes.shop.defaults.action = add
routes.shop.defaults.productid = 0
routes.shop.reqs.productid = \d+
```

Bootstrap.php:

```
... 
protected function _initRoutes() 
    {
        $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.ini', 'routes');
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
        $router->addConfig( $config, 'routes' );
    }
...
```

ShopController.php

```
<?php

class ShopController extends Egil_Controllers_BaseController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
    }

    public function addAction($id)
    {
        echo "the id: ".$id;
    }

}
```

Any suggestions as to why this is not working? I have a feeling I'm missing something fundamental about routing in Zend through .ini files.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I'm more rusty in Zend than I thought. A few minutes after posting I realized I'm trying to access the parameter the wrong way in my controller. It should not be a parameter to addAction, instead I should access it through the request object inside the function:

correct addAction in ShopController:

```
public function addAction()
{
    $id = $this->_request->getParam('productid');
    echo "the id: ".$id;
}
```

I also realized I can simplify my route setup quite a bit in this case:

```
[routes]
routes.shop.route = "shop/:action/:productid"
routes.shop.defaults.controller = shop
routes.shop.defaults.action = index
```