# Zend Framework not include the default module in url

Tags: zend-framework, url, module, default

I have a ZF1.12 project with this structure:

```
|Project
    |-Application
        |-configs
            |-application.ini
        |-modules
            |-default
                |-configs
                |-controllers
                |-models
                |-views
                |-Bootstrap.php
            |-api
                |-configs
                |-controllers
                |-models
                |-views
                |-Bootstrap.php
    |-Bootstrap.php
    |-Library
    |-Public
```

module configuration in application.ini

```
resources.modulesetup[] =
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
resources.modules[] = ""
```

these links

```
$this->url(array('module'=>'default', 'controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'index'));
$this->url(array('module'=>'default', 'controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'one'));
$this->url(array('module'=>'admin', 'controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'index'));
$this->url(array('module'=>'admin', 'controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'two'));
```

at /project.com/ return

```
/project.com/                     ---> works
/project.com/                     ---> no module, no controller and no action...
/project.com/admin/               ---> works
/project.com/admin/               ---> no controller and no action...
```

and the same links at /project.com/default/ return

```
/project.com/                     ---> works
/project.com/index/one            ---> doesn't work and return 404 error 
/project.com/admin/index/index    ---> works
/project.com/admin/index/two      ---> works
```

Something is wrong, of course, I should have always the same return.
The **second** one, also, gives me a 404 error.. I aspected something like  **/project.com/default/index/one** that works if I put it in the address bar in browser.

**Why the url() method does not return the url with the "default" module included?**

Comment: Is /example the module you wish to call?

Comment: /example is the name of the project (domain name). like www.example.com/module/controller/action.... why does it not return also the module between the domain (example) and the controller (index) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, and use a custom route:

```
[routes]    
routes.mycustomroute.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.mycustomroute.route = "([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)"
routes.mycustomroute.defaults.module = "default"
routes.mycustomroute.map.1 = controller
routes.mycustomroute.map.2 = action
routes.mycustomroute.reverse = "%s/%s/%s"
```

Some good details for using routes: [action parameters routing not working in Zend framework routes.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985273/action-parameters-routing-not-working-in-zend-framework-routes-ini).

But basically, in your bootstrap add the function `_initRoutes` (from previous link), and create a routes.ini file under `/configs` with the above

--

Also, you may also want to look into `$front->setParam('useDefaultControllerAlways', true);` (see docs http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html). But I'm unsure of what it does.

Comment: Can you explain me how should I custom this setup? If I put it in the top of the application.ini, nothing changes...

Comment: In your routes.ini, did you add `[routes]` at the very top?

Comment: yes, I did... and nothing... I'm going crazy with this problem :(

Comment: Instead of chaining the default route, try creating a new route, so the above would read `routes.mycustomroute.type`